# Using to strcpy() to get parts of a char* causes a program crash

Tags: c++, winapi, cstring

I am trying to grab bits from a char* then store it in a map. I use strcpy & strncpy to do this but my program crashes when I go to use strncpy (it compiles but crashes at runtime).

Why is my program crashing & how can I successfully grab bits from the char* and store them in a map?

**EDIT: after taking advice I have initialised the char* but it still crashes?**

```
// I did the following
char* variable = "";  
char* value    = ""; 


map <string, string> GetEvironmentVariablesEx()
{
   map <string, string> envVariables;
   char* environVar = GetEnvironmentStrings();
   char* pos        = strchr( environVar, '\0' );

   // This is what environVar contains: environVar = "=::=::\0APPDATA=c:/users/user1/desktop\0OS=windowsNT\0\0"; // note the string is double null terminated

   // Skip over the "=::=::\0" of the environVar string
   if ( pos != NULL ) { environVar = ++pos; pos = strchr( environVar, '\0' ); }
   else return envVariables;


   while ( true )
   {
       char* delim = strchr( environVar, '=' );
       char* variable;
       char* value;

       if ( delim == NULL ) { printf("Environment variable string is badly formatted"); break; }

       // The crash occurs at the below line: the crash occurs at runtime
       strncpy( variable, environVar, strlen(delim) );  
       strcpy( value, environVar+strlen(delim) );  
       printf( "Variable is: %s = %s \n", variable, value );

       envVariables.insert( pair<string, string>(string(variable), string(value)) );
       environVar = ++pos;

       // find the "\0\0" that identifies the end of environVar
       if ( pos != NULL && *pos == 0 ) { break; }

       pos = strchr( environVar, '\0' );
   }

   FreeEnvironmentStrings( environVar ); 
   return envVariables;       
}
```

Comment: Why are you so insistent upon using the harder-to-use `<cstring>` functions instead of the C++ `std::string` functionality?

Comment: Under what circumstance do you imagine that `strchr(environVar, '\0')` would ever return NULL?

Answer (score 3):

The crash is because of following:

```
char* variable; // un allocated or uninitialized
char* value; // un allocated or uninitialized
```

The best way is to use `std::string`. e.g.

```
std::string variable, value;
variable = environVar;
value = environVar + strlen(delim);
```

On the side note, you should `return` (or handle as an error) from the function when you encounter:

```
if ( delim == NULL )
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are doing a String-Copy (`strncpy`) into `variable`.

`variable` is declared as a `char*`, but I do not see that you allocate any memory for it, or otherwise assign a value to `variable`.

As a result, `variable` contains a random memory address, and you are copying a piece of your `environVar` into an unknown piece of memory, resulting in a crash.

To fix this, you should use `malloc` to allocate some memory to `variable` before calling `strncpy`.

**EDIT**:  After your recent change, your code now has:

```
char* variable = "";
```

and later:

```
char* variable;
```

The second declaration of `variable` is **still** uninitialized, and hides (*shadows*) the first declaration.   Thus, you haven't fixed the problem at all.

When I suggest using `malloc` to allocate memory, this is what I'm talking about:

```
variable = malloc(strlen(delim)); 
strncpy( variable, environVar, strlen(delim) );
```

Note that anytime you allocate memory, such as with `malloc`, you must be prepared to free it when you are done.  Otherwise your program will have a memory leak.

Comment: Why do you recommend using `malloc` instead of, say, `std::vector<char>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
char* variable;  
char* value;
```

You need to assign memory to this dynamically or make it a array on stack before you copy any data to these. These are just pointers and they don't have any memory to opy any data into.

To convert char* to string to add into map, use:

```
char* data = ...; 
int size = ...; 
std::string myString(data, size);
```

EDIT: Ideally, You should use a `vector` to manage your character string without the hassles of dynamic allocations or not knowing max size of the character string before hand.

```
vector<char>value;    
vector<char>variable;
```

With this you don't have to bother anymore about the sizes, the vector itself takes care of growing to the size automatically.

Comment: Why do you recommend managing the dynamically allocated array manually instead of using, say, `std::vector<char>`?

Comment: @James McNellis: That is a most valid, most appropriate solution, the OP seems to be really dabbling in procedural C++ realm(insistence of using `cstring`)